# Can I enter Bahrain via Saudi by road ? Indian passport holder, UAE Residence (work permit)

Tags: indian-citizens, driving, uae, saudi-arabia, bahrain

I am Indian Passport holder.

I have UAE residence of 2 years. I have Emirates ID.

I am currently in Saudi Arabia with on Business Visit Visa.

Can I enter Bahrain via Causeway? By taking SAPTCO Bus?

My Visa allows exit from road.

Previously I tried the same as Bahrain gov website says that any GCC Residence holder can enter via Road. But was denied to board the bus as my Visa was just by air. Now I got new one and it allows exit by Road. I have gone to UAE by Road and there I faced no problems (maybe because I am UAE resident ?).

I need to know that now that I have exit allowed by Road, will Kingdom of Bahrain grant me entry on Emirates ID? Will I be allowed to exit Saudi?